# Find the last row matches a criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need some help to create an sql query for Sql server to find the last row that matches a criteria.

I need to find the last `dAuditdate` for this person if his `tech1` or `tech2` or `tech3` is `233`. In this case I need to get 7/15/2015's row  as the `dAuditdate`. Can you please help.Any help would be appreciated.

```
iPersonID   sNameFirst  sNameLast   dAuditUpdate    tech1   tech2   tech3
75605       Jeff        Plutter     10/29/2013      233     0       0
75605       Jeff        Plutter     10/29/2013      233     0       0
75605       Jeff        Plutter     7/15/2014       233     0       0
75605       Jeff        Plutter     7/15/2014       15      0       0
75605       Jeff        Plutter     **7/15/2014**   15      **233** 259
75605       Jeff        Plutter     7/25/2014       15      233     259
1377905     Jeff        Plutter     1/31/2015       15      233     0
```

I tried using `top 1 record order by  dAuditUpdate  DESC` and is not working.

Comment: sorry, data is not formated.   this is one row                                                                                 
75605 Jeff Plutter 7/15/2014 15 233 259

Comment: and the last row is " 75605  Jeff Plutter 1/31/2015 15 233 0"  (ie 75605 instead of 1377905)

Comment: I am not sure if the record you are expecting is correct.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you are using Microsoft SQL Server.

Unfortunately there is no in-built last-method.

But you could use `ordering` and `TOP` to get the last record..

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM your_table
WHERE (tech1 = 233 OR tech2 = 233 OR tech3 = 233)
ORDER BY iPersonID DESC
```

Comment: I'm surprised you could even understand the question without the title.

Comment: Sorry,did not work.I tried like this but not correct.                              select  iPersonID, sNameFirst, sNameLast, sBAC ,dAuditUpdate,tech2,tech1,tech2  from 
(
select top 1  iPersonID, sNameFirst, sNameLast, sBAC ,dAuditUpdate,tech2,tech1,tech2  
from  tPersonAudit  
where ipersonID  In 
  (75605)  --test for one person
order by dAuditUpdate  DESC
 )  t
 where 
  dAuditUpdate <='1/20/2015'   -- --6 month or more
 AND (tech1 = 233 OR tech2 = 233 OR tech3 = 233)

Comment: why are you using the subselect?
try this: SELECT iPersonID, sNameFirst, sNameLast, sBAC,dAuditUpdate, tech2, tech1, tech2
   FROM tPersonAudit
   WHERE iPersonID = 75605
   AND dAuditUpdate <='1/20/2015'
   AND (tech1 = 233 OR tech2 = 233 OR tech3 = 233)
   ORDER BY dAuditUpdate DESC

Comment: If i use that query and use the top 1, it will give me the dAuditUpdate     as 1/31/2015  ( from the result above -That result is for one ipersonid=75605).Since he is in the 233 as tech2 , I need to get the date he joined as 233.In the result above, I need to get the 3rd row from last with an dAuditUpdate     of  7/15/2014 (marked  with ** on both sides)

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand what you want to achieve.. please precise your problem and describe it so that everyone can understand it